# Django Oscar "ProgrammingError at /admin/" MySQL table

Tags: mysql, django, django-oscar

Trying to make my second Django app: a shop based on Django Oscar. I'm following the tutorial on RTFD. I have an issue with this stage http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html#creating-product-classes-and-fulfillment-partners.

> Every Oscar deployment needs at least one product class and one
>   fulfillment partner. These aren’t created automatically as they’re
>   highly specific to the shop you want to build. The quickest way to set
>   them up is to log into the Django admin interface at
>   localhost:8000/admin/ and create instances of both there. For a
>   deployment setup, we recommend creating them as data migration.

However when I try to log into the admin the error generated is:

```
ProgrammingError at /admin/

(1146, "Table 'winestoreoscar.django_admin_log' doesn't exist")
....
Error during template rendering

In template /home/david/.virtualenvs/winestoreoscar/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html, error at line 65
1146
```

This template is shown in the error with this line highlighted:

```
 <ul class="actionlist">
**65    {% for entry in admin_log %}**
66  <li class="{% if entry.is_addition %}addlink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_change %}changelink{% endif %}{% if entry.is_deletion %}deletelink{% endif %}">
```

So it looks like I'm missing a table. I'm using MySQL as the database. In the mysql prompt I tried the obvious..

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE winestoreoscar.django_admin_log;
```

but got the error message...

```
ERROR 1113 (42000): A table must have at least 1 column
```

I then tried removing the whole for loop in the admin template, and admin rendered successfully, but attempting to save resulted in the previous error.

Now I'm stuck. Any help very much appreciated.

Edit:
Here's the tree from the base dir (Thinks - do I need an admin.py..?):

```
├── manage.py
└── oscarwinestore
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── __init__.pyc
    ├── settings.py
    ├── settings.py~
    ├── settings.pyc
    ├── urls.py
    ├── urls.py~
    ├── urls.pyc
    ├── wsgi.py
    └── wsgi.pyc
```

my urls.py is

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from oscar.app import application
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),

    # The Django admin is not officially supported; expect breakage.
    # Nonetheless, it's often useful for debugging.
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'', include(application.urls)),
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the tables with `syncdb` and `migrate`, as per [the docs](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internals/getting_started.html#database):

```
$ python manage.py syncdb --noinput
$ python manage.py migrate
```

Have you done that?

Comment: this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Ohh. Even though it may be a comment..! It was right. I did run syncdb and migrate previously. I then added from django.contrib import admin and admin.autodiscover() to the urls.py as they (for some strange reason) were missing in the build. Running Sync/migrate again fixed it. You guys are the best. Problem solved.

Comment: Huh? He hadn't created the tables, as evidenced by the error. I suggested he create the tables using ``syncdb`` and ``migrate``. How would you have liked me to answer the question?

Comment: yes sorry, edit the question plz, to upvote you. @DominicRodger